# Emission material is not rendered.

Tags: rendering

When I try to render the emission material I just got the black screen, what could be the problem ??

[image: Material view]

[image: rendered view]

[Download Blender File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mjuLOz-the4UrYCOz-UnkJqubg8thjyO)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you might have unintentionally set your sampling settings really low. Go to: Properties>Sampling>Settings>Clamp Dir: and set it to 0 (off) or a much higher setting than 0.01.

Please see this answer for more details: [What is Clamp Direct/Indirect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93955/what-is-clamp-direct-indirect)