# Red dots when rendering

Tags: rendering

Every time I try to render an object, red dots appear all over it (you have to enlarge the image to see them). How do I stop this from happening?

[image]

Comment: you have to make the image fullscreen to see them

Comment: Please make an image that shows the issue clearly.

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/why-do-fireflies-increase-with-number-of-samples-when-using-a-hdri-light-source/41816#41816 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93955/what-is-clamp-direct-indirect/93962#93962