# Array light set to 100k strength isn't bright enough

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have an array lamp set facing up a, moved down a bit so it will give a glow on the top edges. But no matter how big I make the number it won't make it brighter. I can't move it any higher up or else the camera will see a dark spot under the light. How can I fix this, and is there a better way to light it? Im using cycles.

[image]

Comment: Make sure the scene is in real world scale.

Comment: Are you using any clamping for direct light in the render settings? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em7QF.png

Comment: @susu direct clamping is set to 0, direct set to 2.

Comment: @brockmann I have it set to imperial, 1.76x 1.76y 2.59z

Comment: That is the issue right there. When you clamp direct light to 2, then you are limiting how bright lights can be, it doesn't matter if you set the intensiti to two million, values past 2 will be clipped. If you are using filmic, 2 is not white, but a light gray. read: [what is clamp direct/indirect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93955/what-is-clamp-direct-indirect)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emissive shader does not change much in changes of orders of magnitudes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207042/emissive-shader-does-not-change-much-in-changes-of-orders-of-magnitudes) and [emission shader does not bring enough light](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45195/cycles-emission-shader-does-not-bring-enough-light)

Comment: @susu i ended up just cranking up the strength.

Answer (score 0):

Setting it to 1 MW seems to work.

Comment: I bet it does! You'd need a nuclear reactor to power that lamp! :D